# What's useEffect execution order and its internal clean-up logic when requestAnimationFrame and cancelAnimationFrame are used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hooks

According to react document, `useEffect` will trigger clean-up logic before it re-runs `useEffect` part.

> If your effect returns a function, React will run it when it is time to clean up...
>
> There is no special code for handling updates because `useEffect` handles them by default. It cleans up the previous effects before applying the next effects...

However, when I use `requestAnimationFrame` and `cancelAnimationFrame` inside `useEffect`, I found the cancelAnimationFrame may not stop the animation normally. Sometimes, I found the old animation still exists, while the next effect brings another animation, which causes my web app performance issues (especially when I need to render heavy DOM elements).

I don't know whether react hook will do some extra things before it executes the clean-up code, which make my cancel-animation part not work well, will `useEffect` hook do something like closure to lock the state variable?

What's useEffect's execution order and its internal clean-up logic? Is there something wrong the code I write below, which makes cancelAnimationFrame can't work perfectly?

Thanks.

```js
//import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const {useState, useEffect} = React;

//import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [startSeconds, setStartSeconds] = useState(Math.random());
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setStartSeconds(Math.random());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      let raf = null;

      const onFrame = () => {
        const currentProgress = startSeconds / 120.0;
        setProgress(Math.random());
        // console.log(currentProgress);
        loopRaf();
        if (currentProgress > 100) {
          stopRaf();
        }
      };

      const loopRaf = () => {
        raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
        // console.log('Assigned Raf ID: ', raf);
      };

      const stopRaf = () => {
        console.log("stopped", raf);
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
      };

      loopRaf();

      return () => {
        console.log("Cleaned Raf ID: ", raf);
        // console.log('init', raf);
        // setTimeout(() => console.log("500ms later", raf), 500);
        // setTimeout(()=> console.log('5s later', raf), 5000);
        stopRaf();
      };
    },
    [startSeconds]
  );

  let t = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    t.push(i);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <text>{progress}</text>
      {t.map(e => (
        <span>{progress}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Did you try to do the same thing with class components? Do results differ?

Comment: `useEffect(() => { setStartSeconds(Math.random());`  Your causing an update while creating your effect, I'm surprised you don't get an infinite loop, I assume React is protecting you here.

Comment: @Keith He has an empty array as the second argument of that `useEffect` call which makes it only execute on mount and unmount. That block is initialization and cleanup only. That being said, he could have just initialized the `useState` call with that value.

Comment: @KyleRichardson  But his second effect has `[startSeconds]`, so there is an extra render for no reason, as really he should have done -> `const [startSeconds, setStartSeconds] = useState(Math.random());`  It's maybe not the reason for the issue, but to me changing state in an effect initialisation doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Keith Ya I know, but it's not the cause of the overall problem. I agree it is an unneeded re-rendering and should be initialized in use state; but the problem he's encountering is because he's using `useEffect` when he should be using `useLayoutEffect`.

Comment: @KyleRichardson @Keith Thanks for the advice, the first calling `setStartSeconds` to change state in the first `useEffect` function is actually unnecessary, I didn't notice this since it's a async fetch data function in my project, and I changed it when I asked thius question. I'll update it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put these three lines of code in a component and you'll see their order of priority.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect')
    return () => {
      console.log('useEffect cleanup')
    }
  })

  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => console.log('requestAnimationFrame'))

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log('useLayoutEffect')
    return () => {
      console.log('useLayoutEffect cleanup')
    }
  })
```

`useLayoutEffect > requestAnimationFrame > useEffect`

The problem you're experiencing is caused by `loopRaf` requesting another animation frame before the cleanup function for `useEffect` is executed.

Further testing has shown that `useLayoutEffect` is always called before `requestAnimationFrame` and that its cleanup function is called before the next execution preventing overlaps.

> Change `useEffect` to `useLayoutEffect` and it should solve your
>   problem.

`useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` are called in the order they appear in your code for like types just like `useState` calls.

You can see this by running the following lines:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect-1')
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect-2')
  })
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log('useLayoutEffect-1')
  })
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log('useLayoutEffect-2')
  })
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it seems I didn't notice the usage differences between `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`, it works for me now.

Comment: Liked the answer but would prefer this to be backed by documentation or some other reliable reference as well (if possible). Thanks!

Comment: Context on why this works: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect

Comment: A demo of the order of execution can be found here as well -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-z95vce?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 53):

One thing that's not clear in the other answers is the order in which the effects run when you have multiple components in the mix. We've been doing work that involves coordination between a parent and it's children via useContext so the order matters more to us.

The behaviour for this changed in React 17 (after this original answer was posted).

**React 17**

`useEffect` is now ordered in the same way as `useLayoutEffect`. IE *all* cleanups are run (starting with the deepest ones) followed by all effects.

```
render parent
render a
render b
layout cleanup a
layout cleanup b
layout cleanup parent
layout effect a
layout effect b
layout effect parent
effect cleanup a
effect cleanup b
effect cleanup parent
effect a
effect b
effect parent
```

**React 16**

Previously `useLayoutEffect` and `useEffect` executed in different ways.

`useLayoutEffect` ran the clean ups of every component (depth first), then ran the new effects of all components (depth first).

Meanwhile `useEffect` ran the clean up and the new effect before moving to the next component (depth first) and then doing the same.

```
render parent
render a
render b
layout cleanup a
layout cleanup b
layout cleanup parent
layout effect a
layout effect b
layout effect parent
effect cleanup a
effect a
effect cleanup b
effect b
effect cleanup parent
effect parent
```

**To test**

```
const Test = (props) => {
  const [s, setS] = useState(1)

  console.log(`render ${props.name}`)

  useEffect(() => {
    const name = props.name
    console.log(`effect ${props.name}`)
    return () => console.log(`effect cleanup ${name}`)
  })

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const name = props.name
    console.log(`layout effect ${props.name}`)
    return () => console.log(`layout cleanup ${name}`)
  })

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setS(s+1)}>update {s}</button>
      <Child name="a" />
      <Child name="b" />
    </>
  )
}

const Child = (props) => {
  console.log(`render ${props.name}`)

  useEffect(() => {
    const name = props.name
    console.log(`effect ${props.name}`)
    return () => console.log(`effect cleanup ${name}`)
  })

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const name = props.name
    console.log(`layout effect ${props.name}`)
    return () => console.log(`layout cleanup ${name}`)
  })

  return <></>
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect as of React 17. As demonstrated in https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-brown-7xdfgw?file=/src/App.js, useEffect cleanups all run before the next effects without interleaving. This is mentioned in the [release notes](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html) ("Clean up all effects before running any next effects.") as well.

Comment: Thanks @devongovett. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 8):

There are two different hooks that you would need to set your eyes on when working with hooks and trying to implement lifecycle functionalities.

As per the docs:

> `useEffect` runs after react renders your component and ensures that
>   your effect callback does not block browser painting. This differs
>   from the behavior in class components where `componentDidMount` and
>   `componentDidUpdate` run synchronously after rendering.

and hence using `requestAnimationFrame` in these lifecycles works seemlessly but has a slight glitch with `useEffect`. And thus useEffect should to be used to when the changes that you have to make do not block visual updates like making API calls that lead to a change in DOM after a response is received.

Another hook that is less popular but is extremely handy when dealing with visual DOM updates is `useLayoutEffect`.  **[As per the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)**

> The signature is identical to useEffect, but it fires synchronously
>   after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and
>   synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside `useLayoutEffect` will
>   be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

So, if your effect is mutating the DOM (via a DOM node ref) and the DOM mutation will change the appearance of the DOM node between the time that it is rendered and your effect mutates it, then **you don’t want to use `useEffect`**. You’ll want to use `useLayoutEffect`. Otherwise the user could see a flicker when your DOM mutations take effect which is exactly the case with `requestAnimationFrame`

```js
//import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const {useState, useLayoutEffect} = React;

//import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [startSeconds, setStartSeconds] = useState("");
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setStartSeconds(Math.random());

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setStartSeconds(Math.random());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(
    () => {
      let raf = null;

      const onFrame = () => {
        const currentProgress = startSeconds / 120.0;
        setProgress(Math.random());
        // console.log(currentProgress);
        loopRaf();
        if (currentProgress > 100) {
          stopRaf();
        }
      };

      const loopRaf = () => {
        raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
        // console.log('Assigned Raf ID: ', raf);
      };

      const stopRaf = () => {
        console.log("stopped", raf);
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
      };

      loopRaf();

      return () => {
        console.log("Cleaned Raf ID: ", raf);
        // console.log('init', raf);
        // setTimeout(() => console.log("500ms later", raf), 500);
        // setTimeout(()=> console.log('5s later', raf), 5000);
        stopRaf();
      };
    },
    [startSeconds]
  );

  let t = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    t.push(i);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <text>{progress}</text>
      {t.map(e => (
        <span>{progress}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!  It seems I didn't notice the usage differences between `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`, sorry for that!