# React useEffect execute initial setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I have a parent component that always needs to retrieve a token first before the subcomponents get executed. As discussed in this post [What is the correct order of execution of useEffect in React parent and child components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352375/what-is-the-correct-order-of-execution-of-useeffect-in-react-parent-and-child-co) the subcomponents useEffect gets executed first.

My question is how can I handle retrieving the token on initial loading (in the main component)?

Comment: You can get token then render the children, for example {token && <><Child1 /><Child2 /></>}

Comment: Did you try with empty brackt?
useEffect(() => {
   // your code
  }, []);

Comment: Yes the problem is that the useEffect of subcomponents gets executed before the higher up components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a state to track if the session has been initialized.
If the session has not been initialized its displaying a loading animation.
This is only executed on the initial loading of the app.
The loading component can't have a useEffect that requires the api with a valid token or user information.

```js
function App() {
  const [hasSession, setSession] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function initUserProfile() {
      await apiService.init()
      setSession(true)
    }

    initUserProfile()
  }, [])

  if (hasSession === false) {
    return (<Loading />)
  }

  return (
    <Router>...</Router>
  )
 }
```