# How React know it has to run cleanup function on unmount/dependency update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This question is something more related to understanding internal workings of useEffect. I have read few of the articles but couldn’t find the answer to the question.

[What's useEffect execution order and its internal clean-up logic in react hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781632/whats-useeffect-execution-order-and-its-internal-clean-up-logic-in-react-hooks)

https://www.bussieck.com/useeffect-under-the-hood/

My question specifically is, “How react know it has to run cleanup function?”
When I see useEffect, it takes a callback function and it return a function which is optional and which doesn’t get invoked instantly. So how react figures out to call it on unmount/dependency update?

Answer (score 0):

So you've already read that ordering really matters and React stores "internal data" per hook's position. Similarly how `useState` stores "current value", `useEffect` also can save some internal data: last values for dependencies list(initially it's `[]`) and value returned when last time this specific `useEffect` has run(initially `undefined`).

Then once internal comparison for dependencies says "ok, dependencies are different, need to run this `useEffect` again" React takes result from last call and whether it's a function - runs it without any arguments(cleanup).

Next step effect itself is executed - and whathever it returns - is stored back into slot for current hook, to be checked/run next time.

Sure, also cleanup will be run on unmount. If it is a function.